# Php Oracle connection: oci_connect(): ORA-24315: illegal attribute type error

Tags: php, oracle

I am trying to connect to Oracle database using php in windows.

```
$db = "BLM = (DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = host)(PORT = 1521))
(CONNECT_DATA =
  (SERVER = DEDICATED)
  (SERVICE_NAME = blm)
)
)";
$conn = oci_connect('blmuser', 'blmuser', $db);

if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

I am getting the error
    `oci_connect(): ORA-24315: illegal attribute type`

I have tried setting the instant client path but to no avail.

phpinfo()
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Solved the issue. I was trying with only php_oci8_11g.dll enabled in php.ini. Enabled php_oci8.dll extension and everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `BLM=` as you need to give the description only as connection identifier. The former is needed, when you want to refer the alias name (BLM) as in `tnsnames.ora` instead of the full description.

```
$db = "(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = host)(PORT = 1521))
(CONNECT_DATA =
  (SERVER = DEDICATED)
  (SERVICE_NAME = blm)
)
)";
```

Answer (score -1):

Notice how the marked extensions are ordered:

[image]

You should have `extension=php_oci8.dll` and then `extension=php_oci8_11g.dll`:

[image]

Comment: Please don't use images of code as answers. How will the OP copy-paste the code if needed?