# connection laravel and oracle by yajra

Tags: php, oracle, laravel, laravel-5, frameworks

I almost gave up, before there is no problem but after I reinstall the oracle why laravel can't connect.

This error as I can when running the migrate:

```
 c:\xampp\htdocs\tester>php artisan migrate


  [Yajra\Pdo\Oci8\Exceptions\Oci8Exception]
  ORA-24315: illegal attribute type
```

file .env ->

```
DB_CONNECTION=oracle
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=1521
DB_DATABASE=corsys
DB_USERNAME=tester
DB_PASSWORD=orcl
```

oracle.php in the folder config ->

```
<?php

return [
    'oracle' => [
        'driver'        => 'oracle',
        'tns'           => env('DB_TNS', ''),
        'host'          => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port'          => env('DB_PORT', '1521'),
        'database'      => env('DB_DATABASE', 'corsys'),
        'username'      => env('DB_USERNAME', 'tester'),
        'password'      => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'orcl'),
        'charset'       => env('DB_CHARSET', 'AL32UTF8'),
        'prefix'        => env('DB_PREFIX', ''),
        'prefix_schema' => env('DB_SCHEMA_PREFIX', ''),
    ],
];
```

please help me  :(

Comment: Have you enabled the oracle driver for PHP? http://stackoverflow.com/a/26213384/1739852

Comment: Thanks I forgot this part

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable your oracle driver for PHP to be able to access your oracle database.

Related answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26213384/1739852